# Deleted document version but database didn't free up any space

Tags: sharepoint-server

My SharePoint Content database is almost filled up.
I deleted a large document library version, the database didn't free up any space.
What should I do now? Please need your help.

Thank you in advance.
Sincerely,

Farook Golam

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, delete the document library version doesn't solve your problem very well. I suggest you create a new content database and migrate some site collections to the new content database.
You can use the PowerShell command Move-SPSite to move site collections between content databases. There are two options: move a single site collection or multiple site collections to a new content database.
First, make sure you have the corresponding permissions.
Second, open the SharePoint Management Shell.
Then, enter the following command:

```
Move-SPSite <http://ServerName/Sites/SiteName> -DestinationDatabase <DestinationContentDb>
```

[image: To move a single site collection to new content database]
For more details, please refer to this:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/move-site-collections-between-databases

For more information, see [Move-SPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Move-SPSite?view=sharepoint-ps&preserve-view=true).

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? 

If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback if there is any update. 

Please remember to update this thread if you have any progress. 

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Is there anything else I can help with regarding this issue? 
You can comment us at any time and we will continue to follow up.